# sendmail: Redirect one specific mail [virtusertable does not work]

Tags: email, sendmail

I do not have any experience with sendmail and googling around didn't help me so far.

I need to redirect every email that goes to a specific address to another address in the same domain. For example, **info@domain.com** should be redirected to **foo.bar@domain.com**, while every other mail for that domain should be directly be sent.

I have added following entry in the **/etc/mail/virtusertable** file:

```
info@domain.com info
```

and added an *info* alias, pointing to the specific mail in **/etc/aliases**:

```
info: foo.bar@domain.com
```

However, when I try to send a mail to info@domain.com, sendmail does not redirect the mail. I ran **newaliases** and **make**. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendmail applies virtusertable to **some** domains.
Is the domain on list of loacl email domains (`$=w`) or virtual domains (`$={VirtHost}`)?

As root execute the following test commands:

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
echo '$={VirtHost}' | sendmail -bt
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both commands are yielding  
`WARNING: local host name (ba7411d5b464) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>`

Comment: 1) it should be lowercase w not uppercase W 2) "Who am I" documentation is available on-line at https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/whoami.html

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Undo what you did
Step 2) In /etc/aliases append `"info: foo.bar"`
Step 3) Run /usr/bin/newaliases
Step 4) Use postfix